# How to use str.format() with a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

What is wrong with this piece of code?

```
dic = { 'fruit': 'apple', 'place':'table' }
test = "I have one {fruit} on the {place}.".format(dic)
print(test)

>>> KeyError: 'fruit'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952344/how-do-i-format-a-string-using-a-dictionary-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Should be

```
test = "I have one {fruit} on the {place}.".format(**dic)
```

Note the [`**`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).  [`format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples) does not accept a single dictionary, but rather keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you update the answer to explain why I have to add `**` before the dictionary?

Comment: @bogdan, the `**` indicates that the dictionary should be expanded to a list of keyword parameters. The `format` method doesn't take a dictionary as a parameter, but it does take keyword parameters.

Comment: @bogdan: Added two links to my answer.  The reason basically is "because the documentation says so".

Comment: @bogdan That just tells Python that you are providing a dictionary to the function so that it can provide the values in the dictionary, rather than the dictionary itself. You can do the same when calling any function. If function 'f' takes the args 'a','b', and 'c', you could use `dic = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}` and call `f(**dic)`.

Comment: The reason is that `"I have one {0[fruit]} on the {0[place]}.".format(dic)` works too - `dic` is the 0th positional argument here and you can access it's keys in the template.

Answer (score 11):

There is [`''.format_map()` function](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format_map#str.format_map) since Python 3.2:

```
test = "I have one {fruit} on the {place}.".format_map(dic)
```

The advantage is that it accepts any mapping e.g., a class with `__getitem__` method that generates values dynamically or `collections.defaultdict` that allows you to use non-existent keys.

It can be emulated on older versions:

```
from string import Formatter

test = Formatter().vformat("I have one {fruit} on the {place}.", (), dic)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code too:

```
dic = { 'fruit': 'apple', 'place':'table' }
print "I have one %(fruit)s on the %(place)s." % dic
```

If you want to know more about format method use: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: The `%` operator shouldn't be used in new code according to the Python documentation.

Comment: Could you please give me a reference so i will be able to read more on this?

Comment: Thank you very much), will try to avoid using it from now

Comment: @Mark: `%` was meant to be deprecated in Python 3.1, but they never did.  It won't go away soon (or probably not at all), so it's ok to still use it.

Comment: @Sven, good to know, thanks. Still I'd go with `format` first because it's recommended, second because it seems cleaner.

Comment: @MarkRansom it is absolutely required to use `%` format in many cases. One example is: `logging.debug("Message with %(expensive_out)s" % expensive_out=expensive_func())` If f-string format is used, `expensive_func()` will be called only to have the constructed string thrown away (assuming debug logging is disabled).