# Formatted string with calculated values in Python

Tags: python, string, f-string

In JavaScript I can use a template literal and include calculate values. For example:

```js
var a = 3;
var b = 8;
var text = `Adding ${a} + ${b} = ${a+b}`;   //  Adding 3 + 8 = 11
```

I know python has `f'…'` strings and `str.format()` with placeholder. Is there a way I can include a calculation in the string?

Comment: Simply ```f'{a} + {b} = {a + b}'``` will do - That is basically like ```a,"+",b,"=",a+b```

Comment: f-strings support embedded calculations. What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `f-string`:

```
a = 3
b = 8    
text = f'{a} + {b} = {a + b}'
```

The `text` variable in this case is a string containing `'3 + 8 = 11'`.

Using `str.format`:

```
a = 3
b = 8
text = '{0} {1} = {2}'.format(a, b, a + b)
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Is this possible using `str.format()`?

Comment: @Manngo Yes, it's possible, please refer to [this thread for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229671/how-to-use-str-format-with-a-dictionary-in-python).

Comment: Probably `'{a} + {b} = {a + b}'.format(**{'a': a, 'b': b, 'a + b': a + b})`. but this is very much a bunch of repeated tokens.  Just use f-strings.

Comment: From the [`str.format` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), it can be both `*args` or `**kwargs`, so using positional args is less verbose (for simplicity)

Comment: So, the answer appears to be that the expression in the `.format()` method `{…}` is strictly a key, not an evaluated expression. On the other hand, in the f-string, it is evaluated.

Comment: @Manngo correct; f-strings in Python is the template string analogue in Node.js/JavaScript (analogue due to certain differences as some of the Python's `.format()` conventions are carried over, which are absent in Node.js/JavaScript). The expression in `.format()` follows the arguments and/or keys specified, which is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) briefly - follow the Format String Syntax link in there for further documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.format`:

```
a = 3
b = 8    
text = '{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(a,b,a+b)
print(text)
```

Using `f-string`:

```
f'{a} + {b} = {a + b}'
```

All of them do the same thing as:

```
a,"+",b,"=",a+b
```

Comment: The tokens for `.format` has been changed and differs from the intent of the OP's question (they should be provided as names).  Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229671/how-to-use-str-format-with-a-dictionary-in-python) for what should be done instead (i.e. pass in a series of keywords).