# Does PHP have a feature like Python's template strings?

Tags: php, string, templates, template-variables

Python has a feature called [template strings](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/node40.html).

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template('$who likes $what')
>>> s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
'tim likes kung pao'
```

I know that PHP allows you to write:

```
"Hello $person"
```

and have `$person` substituted, but the templates can be reused in various sections of the code?

Comment: **See:** https://packagist.org/packages/nicmart/string-template

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You could also use [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$template = '$who likes $what';

$vars = array(
  '$who' => 'tim',
  '$what' => 'kung pao',
);

echo strtr($template, $vars);
```

Outputs:

```
tim likes kung pao
```

Comment: One of the cons of this approach is that no IDE can help you validating the template and its parameters, you're basically on your own.

Comment: This is a better approach when storing/retrieve a string externally while maintaining the parameters (instead of values at that time). e.g. when using a database

Answer (score 90):

You can use template strings like this:

```php
$name = "Maria";
$info["last_name"] = "Warner";

echo "Hello {$name} {$info["last_name"]}";
```

This will echo `Hello Maria Warner`.

Comment: This template string approach is similar to the template string approach in Javascript.

Comment: This one should be the right answer. Only one thing, why does it not work with single apices?

Comment: @EuberDeveloper Not sure, but for example the same as " $var="A" and echo " $var " works and  ' $var ' does not? (notice single quotes)

Comment: @Miguel I tried on repl.it exactly the above code of the commented answer. If you substitute the " with the ', it stops working. But, reading php docs, it seems the normal behaviour

Comment: @EuberDeveloper Right, it is related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: What's the point in adding brackets here? It looks to be the same as using `"Hello $name $info[last_name]}"` in your code: [try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkVfISc1MVbBWUfBOLMhOVrLlUMvPS8qOVchKLS@JBckqxINnwxKK81CKgNFdqcka@gpJHak5OvkI1WHctkMbQVAtUC1EakwdnQnRBrIRogeuIVbL@/x8A)

Comment: your missing the point, you can do it of course, but this is just to demonstrate that you can do it, even for objects-keys, where is not simple the var value itself. Like you have a context array, and you want to fill with different from from that context array...

Comment: This answer is missing the point. The OP said "but the templates can be reused in various sections of the code". This however can be achieved using `eval()`, see Example #1 in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: I'm really surprised this is so highly voted. It totally misses the point of the question where the template string is defined **before** the variables

Comment: @Phil is correct, this requires the vars to be available for them to "convert", that's what the OP meant with define the template before variables, and re-use. But like Tilman Vogel said, use eval

Answer (score 14):

I think there are a bunch of ways to do this... but this comes to mind.

```
$search = array('%who%', '%what_id%');
$replace = array('tim', 'kung pao');
$conference_target = str_replace(
    $search,
    $replace,
    "%who% likes %what%"
);
```

Ha, we even had one in our framework using [vsprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php):

```
class Helper_StringFormat {

    public static function sprintf($format, array $args = array()) {

        $arg_nums = array_slice(array_flip(array_keys(array(0 => 0) + $args)), 1);

        for ($pos = 0; preg_match('/(?<=%)\(([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\)/', $format, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $pos);) {
            $arg_pos = $match[0][2];
            $arg_len = strlen($match[0][0]);
            $arg_key = $match[1][0];

            if (! array_key_exists($arg_key, $arg_nums)) {
                user_error("sprintfn(): Missing argument '${arg_key}'", E_USER_WARNING);
                return false;
            }
            $format = substr_replace($format, $replace = $arg_nums[$arg_key] . '$', $arg_pos, $arg_len);
            $pos = $arg_pos + strlen($replace);
        }

        return vsprintf($format, array_values($args));
    }
}
```

Which looks like it came from [the sprintf page](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.sprintf.php#94608)

This allows for calls like:

```
sprintfn('second: %(second)s ; first: %(first)s', array(
    'first' => '1st',
    'second'=> '2nd'
));
```

**UPDATE**
Here is an update to do what you want... not fully tested though

```
class Helper_StringFormat {

    public static function sprintf($format, array $args = array()) {
        $arg_nums = array_slice(array_flip(array_keys(array(0 => 0) + $args)), 1);

        for ($pos = 0; preg_match('/(?<=%)\(([a-zA-Z_][\w\s]*)\)/', $format, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $pos);) {
            $arg_pos = $match[0][1];
            $arg_len = strlen($match[0][0]);
            $arg_key = $match[1][0];

            if (! array_key_exists($arg_key, $arg_nums)) {
                user_error("sprintfn(): Missing argument '${arg_key}'", E_USER_WARNING);
                return false;
            }
            $format = substr_replace($format, $replace = $arg_nums[$arg_key] . '$', $arg_pos, $arg_len);
            $pos = $arg_pos + strlen($replace); // skip to end of replacement for next iteration
        }

        return vsprintf($format, array_values($args));
    }
}

$str = "%(my var)s now work with a slight %(my var2)s";
$repl = array("my var" => "Spaces", "my var2" => "modification.");

echo Helper_StringFormat::sprintf($str, $repl);
```

**OUTPUT**
Spaces now work with a slight modification.

Comment: That's nice, except there is no way to escape a `%(some character)` sequence. If I ever get round to fixing this, I'll post the code in this thread

Comment: There is a typo in your second link name BTW. (sprtinf)

Answer (score 9):

Another more simple approach would be this:

```
$s = function ($vars) {
    extract($vars);
    return "$who likes $what";
};
echo $s(['who' => 'Tim', 'what' => 'King Pao']); // Tim likes King Pao
```

And yes, PHPStorm will complain...

Answer (score 5):

I personally most like [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) (or [vsprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php), for an array of arguments).  It places them in the intended order, coerces types as needed, and has a lot more advanced features available.

Example:

```
$var = sprintf("%s costs %.2f dollars", "Cookies", 1.1);
```

This will result in the value `Cookies cost 1.10 dollars`.

There's an entire family of printf functions for different use cases, all listed under "See Also".

Very versatile: same methods for providing variables, array components, function results, etc.

Comment: There's an answer with an additional function/class to simulate sprintf – it's been builtin since PHP 4.

Answer (score 2):

I made a function to do what you want. i made it "quck-and-dirty" because i have not much time to refactorize it, maybe i upload it to my github.

***EDIT: a bug correction...***

Use it like

```
    formattemplatter(
                     '$who likes $what'
                     , array(
                               'who'  => 'Tim'
                             , 'what' => 'Kung Pao'
                     )
    );
```

Variables can be [a-zA-Z0-9_] only.

```
 function formattemplater($string, $params) {
    // Determine largest string
    $largest = 0;
    foreach(array_keys($params) as $k) {
        if(($l=strlen($k)) > $largest) $largest=$l;
    }

    $buff   = '';

    $cp     = false;    // Conditional parenthesis
    $ip     = false;    // Inside parameter
    $isp    = false;    // Is set parameter

    $bl     = 1;    // buffer length
    $param  = '';   // current parameter

    $out    = '';  // output string
    $string .= '!';

    for($sc=0,$c=$oc='';isset($string{$sc});++$sc,++$bl) {
        $c = $string{$sc};

        if($ip) {
            $a = ord($c);

            if(!($a == 95 || (                  // underscore
                    ($a >= 48 && $a <= 57)      // 0-9
                    || ($a >= 65 && $a <= 90)   // A-Z
                    || ($a >= 97 && $a <= 122)  // a-z
                )
            )) {

                $isp = isset($params[$buff]);

                if(!$cp && !$isp) {
                    trigger_error(
                            sprintf(
                                    __FUNCTION__.': the parameter "%s" is not defined'
                                    , $buff
                            )
                            , E_USER_ERROR
                    );
                } elseif(!$cp || $isp) {
                    $out    .= $params[$buff];
                }

                $isp    = $isp && !empty($params[$buff]);
                $oc     = $buff = '';
                $bl     = 0;
                $ip     = false;
            }
        }

        if($cp && $c === ')') {
            $out .= $buff;

            $cp = $isp = false;
            $c  = $buff = '';
            $bl = 0;
        }

        if(($cp && $isp) || $ip)
            $buff .= $c;

        if($c === '$' && $oc !== '\\') {
            if($oc === '(')  $cp = true;
            else $out .= $oc;

            $ip   = true;
            $buff = $c = $oc = '';
            $bl   = 0;
        }

        if(!$cp && $bl > $largest) {
            $buff   = substr($buff, - $largest);
            $bl     = $largest;
        }

        if(!$ip && ( !$cp || ($cp && $isp))) {
            $out .= $oc;
            if(!$cp) $oc = $c;
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness: there is also [Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

```php
$template = fn( $who, $what ) => <<<EOT
    $who likes $what
EOT;

echo( $template( 'tim', 'kung pao' ) );
```

Outputs:

```html
tim likes kung pao
```

Sidenotes:

- You get highlighting in your favourite language (if properly configured). Just substitute EOT (from the sample above) with whatever you like (e.c. HTML, SQL, PHP, ...).
- Escape arrays with curly braces `{$data['who']}`. Accessing objekts like `$data->who` works without braces.
- [Arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) like `fn($a)=>$a` are available since PHP 7.4. You can write `function($a){return $a;}` if you are using PHP<7.4.

Answer (score 1):

An other option is to use

```
<?php

echo msgfmt_format_message('en_GB', 'Tom has {0, plural, =0{no cat} =1{a cat} other{# cats}}', [0]), "\n";
echo msgfmt_format_message('en_GB', 'Tom has {0, plural, =0{no cat} =1{a cat} other{# cats}}', [1]), "\n";
echo msgfmt_format_message('en_GB', 'Tom has {0, plural, =0{no cat} =1{a cat} other{# cats}}', [2]), "\n";

echo msgfmt_format_message('de', 'Tom hat {cat, plural, =0{keine Katze} =1{eine Katze} other{# Katzen}} und {dog} Hunde', ['cat'=>12345, 'dog'=>-5.23]), "\n";

echo MessageFormatter::formatMessage('de', 'Tom hat {cat, plural, =0{keine Katze} =1{eine Katze} other{# Katzen}} und {dog,number} Hunde', ['cat'=>12, 'dog'=>-5.23]), "\n";

$fmt = new MessageFormatter('de', 'Tom hat {cat, plural, =0{keine Katze} =1{eine Katze} other{# Katzen}} und {dog,number} Hunde');
echo $fmt->format(['cat'=>12, 'dog'=>-5.23]);
```